# Python HTML Encoding \xc2\xa0

Tags: python, html, encoding

I've been struggling with this one for a while. I'm trying to write strings to HTML but have issues with the format once I've cleaned them. Here's an example:

```
paragraphs = ['Grocery giant and household name Woolworths is battered and bruised. ', 
'But behind the problems are still the makings of a formidable company']

x = str(" ")
for item in paragraphs:
    x = x + str(item)
x
```

Output:

```
"Grocery giant and household name\xc2\xa0Woolworths is battered and\xc2\xa0bruised. 
But behind the problems are still the makings of a formidable\xc2\xa0company"
```

Desired output:

```
"Grocery giant and household name Woolworths is battered and bruised. 
But behind the problems are still the makings of a formidable company"
```

I'm hoping you're able to explain why this happens and how I can fix. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked for unusual Unicode whitespace in your source string?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

\xc2\xa0 means **0xC2 0xA0** is so-called

> Non-breaking space

It is a kind of invisible control character in UTF-8 encodings. More info about it check the wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

I copied what you have pasted in the questions and got the expected output.

Comment: Thank you. That fixes it. I built in:
x.replace("\xc2\xa0", " ")