# Non-ASCII characters appearing in string

Tags: python

So I need to compare 2 `strings` :

```
str1 = 'this is my string/ndone'
str2 = 'this is my string done'
```

So I replace the new line from `str1` with `' '`:

```
new_str = str1.replace('\n', ' ')
```

And when print the 2 strings there are identical:

```
'this is my string done'
```

But when compared using `==` operator the not so I convert this 2 strings into array to see why they are not equal:

```
arr1 = bytearray(str1 , 'utf-8')
print(arr1)

arr2 = bytearray(str2 , 'utf-8')
print(arr2)
```

And this is the output:

```
str1 = bytearray(b'this is\xc2\xa0my string done')

str2 = bytearray(b'this is my string done')
```

So what is this `\xc2\xa0` ?

Comment: That's a Unicode non-breaking space character.

Comment: Can't we do str1.join(' ') and then compare?

Comment: So how can i remove it, all i want is compare this 2 strings

Comment: How about `.replace('\n', '\x20')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python HTML Encoding \xc2\xa0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419541/python-html-encoding-xc2-xa0)

Comment: What is the source of your strings? Do you read one from a file? If so, please show some more code.

Answer (score 0):

`'\xc2\xa0'` is the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character ['NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm).

Comment: So how can i remove it, all i want is compare this 2 strings

Comment: @falukky You will need to define "compare" carefully here. Are `foo bar` and `foo bar` the same? (The first has a breaking space, the second has a non-breaking space). What about `foo\nbar` and `foo bar`? What about 2 vs. 1 space? I suspect what you really want is some sort of simple regexp.

Answer (score 0):

use python `unidecode` library

```
from unidecode import unidecode

str  = "this is\xc2\xa0my string done"

print(unidecode(str))
```

o/p

```
this isA my string done
```

Comment: Do you have solution without install new module ?

Comment: installing new module is simple . Just run the command  `pip install unidecode` . I use this method only.

Comment: I know but my project run on many machines so i prefer solution without install this module cause several machines is without my control at this moment

Comment: you may then try:
`"this is\xc2\xa0my string done".encode('ascii',"ignore").decode('utf-8')`

o/p: `'this ismy string done'`

Answer (score 0):

== is working in comparing two string

```
str1 = 'this is my string\ndone'
str2 = 'this is my string done'
str1 = str1.replace("\n"," ")
print(str1)
if (str1 == str2):
    print("y")
else:
    print("n")
```

and output is

```
this is my string done
y
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated elsewhere your string had a "/n" not "\n" in it. 
Assuming though that what you wanted to do was normalise all whitespace characters, this is a very handy trick I use all the time:

```
string = ' '.join(string.split())
```

Update: Okay this is why:

If you don't specify what string.split() should use a separater the, per [docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

So it splits on whitspaces, and treats multiple whitespaces as a single seperator. I don't know what characters are all defined as "whitespaces", but is certainly includes all the usual suspects. Then when you rejoin the list into a string with ' '.join(), you know for sure that all whitespaces are now the same.

Comment: Can we also know why -1 ?

Comment: It should be string = ''.join(string.split()), I guess

Comment: Well, erm, depends. If you want a whitespace, but you want them all to be the same, then ' '.join