# Remove non ASCII characters

Tags: python

So i have this string:

```
str1 = 'this is my string'
```

And when convert it to array i can see that it contains `\xc2\xa`:

```
'this is\xc2\xamy string'
```

So when i remove it and print it again:

```
all_ascii = ''.join(char for char in str1 if ord(char) < 128)
all_ascii11 = bytearray(all_ascii, 'utf-8')
print(all_ascii11)
```

My string changed and the space removed:

'this ismy string'

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Why asking again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57163854/non-ascii-characters-appearing-in-string

Comment: Because this is new issue

Comment: just use python `unidecode` library.

Comment: Can i have a simple example ?